# ASP.NET MVC 2: Where to put custom JS files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

what is the recommended place to put .js files - not really talking about jquery etc.... but my own custom js files..

The scripts directory seems to contain ajax, jquery etc... So is this the correct place?

OR would a better place be COntent?

I also was doing a search and saw some arguments for placing the JS files in the VIEWS directory - but is it supported?

Any ideas or comments really appeciated

Is there a document that outlines what each directory should be used for ?

I was thinking of placing my images like this Content/Images

Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that as far as *.js* files are scripts, then you should put them into *Scripts* folder. If you are worried about mixing your own scripts with jquery and all that microsoft stuff, then just put them into separate subfolders.

Answer (score 3):

You'd only want them in the Views directory if you were dynamically creating scripts based on data from the controller. This approach isn't great - you should try and separate Javascript from Html.

Otherwise, Scripts is the best place for them.

Answer (score 0):

I think Scripts folder is the best choice.
Don't put them into Views folders, because when you want to use an existing script in a view folder; it became a nightmare.

Edit: I had a mistake and wrote Content folder. I corrected it now.

Comment: Why content and not the Scripts? Isn't it the best choice?

Comment: I thought Content equals to scripts. I only compaired with Content and Views directories, not sub directories. Of course Content\Scripts is best choice. If you look again, i don't say anything about Scripts folder.

Comment: No.. By default Scripts and Content folders are separate siblings not parent-child.